# How to convert a single char into an int

Tags: c++, char

I have a string of digits, e.g. "123456789", and I need to extract each one of them to use them in a calculation. I can of course access each char by index, but how do I convert it into an int?

I've looked into atoi(), but it takes a string as argument. Hence I must convert each char into a string and then call atoi on it. Is there a better way?

Comment: Why do you need to extract each one, instead of treating a series of digits as an actual number?

Comment: The string is not really a number, but individual digits, To be exact, a social security number. I want to run a calculation validating the ssn.

Comment: Duplicate of [Convert char to int in C and C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5029840/convert-char-to-int-in-c-and-c) (first interpretation)

Answer (score 174, accepted):

You can utilize the fact that the character encodings for digits are all in order from 48 (for '0') to 57 (for '9'). This holds true for ASCII, UTF-x and practically all other encodings (*see comments below for more on this*).

Therefore the integer value for any digit is the digit minus '0' (or 48).

```
char c = '1';
int i = c - '0'; // i is now equal to 1, not '1'
```

is synonymous to

```
char c = '1';
int i = c - 48; // i is now equal to 1, not '1'
```

However I find the first `c - '0'` far more readable.

Comment: Is there any encoding in which '9'-'0' != 9 ? I'm not even sure if such an encoding would be allowed per ISO C++.

Comment: On encodings and the order of digits, I asked this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/782373/are-digits-represented-in-sequence-in-all-text-encodings. The short answer is "Any encoding based on Ascii or EBCDIC, yes" (which means 99.9% of encodings we'll meet in everyday life and the web). Also interestingly the c/c++ standards seem to state that they only support encodings where the digits are ordered.

Comment: Is there any encoding where it does not hold 
'0' < '1' < '2' < '3' 
It would be at least a very very strange decision

Comment: The C++ standard guarantees that `'0'` through `'9'` occur adjacently and in the right order in the character set. So the `c - '0'` works on all systems, whereas `c - 48` wouldn't work on EBCDIC for example.

Comment: @Friedrich — in pre-digital telecoms, with pulse dialling, the `0` digit was 10.  How many clicks did it take to dial `9`?  To dial `0`?  Why is `0` after `9` on keyboards (and below `9` on numeric keypads)?

Comment: Note that C11 [§5.2.1 Character sets ¶3](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#5.2.1p3) says: _In both the source and execution basic character sets, the value of each character after `0` in the above list of decimal digits shall be one greater than the value of the previous._  The C++ standard will have a similar rule.

Answer (score 25):

```
#define toDigit(c) (c-'0')
```

Answer (score 8):

Or you could use the "correct" method, similar to your original atoi approach, but with std::stringstream instead. That should work with chars as input as well as strings. (boost::lexical_cast is another option for a more convenient syntax)

(atoi is an old C function, and it's generally recommended to use the more flexible and typesafe C++ equivalents where possible. std::stringstream covers conversion to and from strings)

Comment: Nice one, my C++ is rusty and I thought there was a safer way but didn't have time to look.

Answer (score 4):

#### You can make use of atoi() function

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    int num ;
    num = atoi(argv[1]);
    printf("\n%d", num);
}
```

Comment: `atoi` converts a string of characters, not a single character like OP wanted

Answer (score 3):

The answers provided are great as long as you only want to handle Arabic numerals, and are working in an encoding where those numerals are sequential, and in the same place as ASCII.

This is almost always the case.

If it isn't then you need a proper library to help you.

Let's start with [ICU](http://site.icu-project.org/).

1. First convert the byte-string to a unicode string. (Left as an exercise for the reader).
2. Then use [uchar.h](http://icu-project.org/apiref/icu4c/uchar_8h.html) to look at each character.
3. if we the character is `UBool   u_isdigit (UChar32 c)`
4. then the value is `int32_t u_charDigitValue     (   UChar32      c       )`

Or maybe ICU has some function to do it for you - I haven't looked at it in detail.

Answer (score 2):

```
#include<iostream>
#include<stdlib>
using namespace std;

void main()
{
     char ch;
     int x;
     cin >> ch;
     x = char (ar[1]);
     cout << x;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I agree with @jalf. Using the [sstream](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/sstream/stringstream/) library and [stoi](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/stoi/) appears to be the recommended approach:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

int main() {

  stringstream st;
  st << 1  << '2';

  cout << stoi(st.str()) + 1; 

  return 0;
}
```

## Output

```
13
```

I am a new student of C++ but a long-time LAMP stack developer. I was hoping the string class had more things to smoothly transition between chars and strings, but I've not yet found such a thing that is natively supported.

Answer (score 1):

If you *are* worried about encoding, you can always use a switch statement.

Just be careful with the format you keep those large numbers in.  The maximum size for an integer in some systems is as low as 65,535 (32,767 signed).  Other systems, you've got 2,147,483,647 (or 4,294,967,295 unsigned)

Comment: How can a simple switch-statement help with different encodings?

Comment: Because unicode digits cover exactly 10 positions, and ascii digits cover exactly 10 positions.

Am I missing something?

Comment: you don't need to be worried about encoding. even if the numbers are not from 48 to 58 - the numbers must all be adjacent in their encoding. so you can still subtract '0' from any digit and get correct results. i believe i read that in the standard

Answer (score 1):

Any problems with the following way of doing it?

```
int CharToInt(const char c)
{
    switch (c)
    {
    case '0':
        return 0;
    case '1':
        return 1;
    case '2':
        return 2;
    case '3':
        return 3;
    case '4':
        return 4;
    case '5':
        return 5;
    case '6':
        return 6;
    case '7':
        return 7;
    case '8':
        return 8;
    case '9':
        return 9;
    default:
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: None, except that it's a lot of duplicated code to do something fairly trivial. Binary Worrier's answer is a lot simpler as long as the input encoding is known, and allows this shortcut. My version is shorter too, and works no matter the encoding, but will be a bit slower.

Comment: @jalf Binary Worrier's answer is guaranteed to work with any C++ or POSIX compliant encoding

Answer (score 1):

By this way You can convert char to int and int to char easily:

```
int charToInt(char c)
{
   int arr[]={0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
   return arr[c-'0'];
}
```

Comment: `arr[x] == x` for all valid values of `x`. Since acessing an array out-of-bound is UB it's possible to assume `arr[x] == x` for all `x`.

Answer (score -1):

For me the following worked quite well:

```
QChar c = '5';
int x = c.digitValue();
// x is now 5
```

Documentation: [int QChar::digitValue() const](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qchar.html#digitValue) which says:

> Returns the numeric value of the digit, or -1 if the character is not
>   a digit.