# How to convert char '5' into int '5' in C?

Tags: c, char, int

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to convert a single char into an int](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/439573/how-to-convert-a-single-char-into-an-int)

I am working on a program that requires an integer be pulled from a string, and then added to other integers.

I.E.  Input "123456789".  I can pull out the 5th char, '5', but I need to add this to another int.  If I try to convert this to int, it returns the ASCI value.  Is there any way to convert a char to its corresponding int?

Answer (score 9):

Just subtract away the ASCII value of character `'0'`.

e.g. `'5' - '0' = 5`

Comment: Note that that also works in EBCDIC :)

Comment: @DanielFischer: Thank so much for your comment. What will happen if using ASCII?

Comment: @Jack It will work too. Daniel noted that because some similar tricks (for example, `'f'-'a'==5`) don't work in EBCDIC.

Comment: @asaelr That one in particular does work in EBCDIC, the splits are between 'i' and 'j' and between 'r' and 's' (yeah, I had to look it up, why do you ask?).

Comment: Thanks. (I talked about the general case, and did not look up :) ,also, for some reason, I thought that there are more splits.)