# reading string text input to create a 2D Vector

Tags: c++, algorithm, stdvector

Given a regular text file of:

```
56789
28385
43285
22354
34255
```

I am trying to read each string character in the text file and store them in a 2D vector.

First I would like to take each string row. Then I would like to take each character in the row and convert into an int then push_back into the row. Then I'd like to repeat for each line.

When outputting each column and row in my 2D vector, I would like the same exact output of:

```
56789 //each number an int now instead of a string
28385
43285
22354
34255
```

**My issue** is that I try to use `i = stoi(j);` which gives the error:

```
No matching function for call to 'stoi'
```

I do have the correct `#include` to be able to use `stoi()`

```
vector<vector<int>> read_file(const string &filename) 
{
    string file, line; stringstream convert; int int_convert, counter;
    vector<vector<int>> dot_vector;

    file = filename;
    ifstream in_file;
    in_file.open(file);

    while (getline(in_file, line)) {
        counter++; //how many lines in the file
    }

    char current_char;
    while (getline(in_file, line)) {
        for (int i = 0; i < counter; i++) {
            vector<int> dot_row;
            for (int j = 0; j < line.size(); j++) {
                current_char = line[j];
                i = stoi(j); //this is giving me an error
                dot_row.push_back(i);
            }
            dot_vector.push_back(dot_row);
        }
    }

    in_file.close();
    return dot_vector;
}
```

Comment: `std::stoi` requires you to include `<string>`.

Comment: After counting all the lines in the file, the file pointer as at the end. Also, what is `counter` for anyway?

Comment: @JohnnyMopp I was thinking of using counter to read the number of lines so when I iterate in the for loop the range will only iterate until the counter. Is there a more convenient way?

Comment: I don't see why you need `counter` at all. `while(getline(in_file, line)) {` should be sufficient.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp got it, thanks for your suggestion!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here

```
 i = stoi(j);
 // j is integer already
```

[std::stoi](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol#Parameters) 
    expect a string as the argument and what you providing is an `int`.

You can either convert the **char to string** and call `std::stoi` like follows

```
std::string CharString(1, line[j]);
dot_row.emplace_back(std::stoi(CharString));
```

or can convert the **char to int** directly while keeping to the vector:

```
dot_row.emplace_back(static_cast<int>(line[j] - '0'));
```

---

You have other problems in your code. Like in the comments mentioned, you do not need the extra counting of lines. Once you have your first `while` loop, you will reach already end of your file. The code after is then meaningless.

Secondly, you do not need two `for loops`. Simply use a range-based for loop for each `line` of strings and while iterating through it, convert to integer and save to vector.

```
while (getline(in_file, line)) 
{
    std::vector<int> dot_row; dot_row.reserve(str.size());
    for (const std::string& eachChar: line) 
    {
        std::string CharString(1, eachChar);
        dot_row.push_back(std::stoi(CharString));
        // or other option mentioned above
    }
    dot_vector.push_back(dot_row);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This was helpful. Why is the - '0' needed in (line[j] - '0')?

Comment: @Dracep because in ASCII code, [the numbers (digits) start from 48](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/439573/how-to-convert-a-single-char-into-an-int)

Comment: appreciate the feedback that you gave! This made more sense reading the while and for loop. I got a little confused using 2D vectors and needing two for loops.

Comment: @Dracep glad that I could help you out. However, I would strongly [suggest reading good books](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list), which help you more to understand C++.