# How to convert a specific character from a string into an int (C)

Tags: c

I'm trying to convert a character from a string into an int. I tried this :

```
int function(char c[]) {
     return (int)c[1];
}
```

I want to convert only the second character of the string c, which length is only of two.

The problem with this function is that the integer returned is completely different from what I typed.

I also tried to compare c[1] and numbers from 0 to 10 (only those numbers need to be converted), but there's a problem with c[1].

I hope everything is clear enough so you can help me.

Thanks !!!

**Answer :** I just changed `return(int)c[1];` into `return(int)(c[1]-'0');` and that worked well, at least for me

Comment: Please post the [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) with complete code (perhaps a dozen more lines) that demonstrates the problem, and show *what* you typed.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert a single char into an int](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/439573/how-to-convert-a-single-char-into-an-int)

Comment: If `c` contains a digit `'0'`..`'9'`, then to get an integer value `0`..`9`, you need `c - '0'`.  The value of `'0'` is usually 48 — in code sets based on ISO 8859 (and ASCII).  Only in EBCDIC (used by some mainframes) is the value different; there, `'0'` is usually 240.

Comment: Thanks Jonathan Leffler, that worked perfectly fine for me

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to convert the char into its ASCII (integer) form.

```
printf("The ASCII value of %c = %d\n",i,i);
```

If you want to convert an integer into char, simply use explicit casting like below:

```
char c1 = (char)97;  //c1 = 'a'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int function(char c[]);

int main(void) {
    char characters[3] = {'a','b','c'};

    int a = function(characters);

    printf ("%d",a);

    return 0;
}

int function(char c[]) {
     return (int)c[1];
}
```

Answer (score -1):

try this:-

```
int function(char c[]) {
    int x=0;
    try {
        x = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(c[1]));
    }catch (NumberFormatException e){
        x=c[1];
    }
    return x;
}
```

Comment: Using a C++ construct (`try { … } catch …`) in C code (the question is tagged [tag:c] and not [tag:c++]) isn't helpful. Your code converts the second character in `c` to a string, parses the string to see if it is an integer, and captures an exception to spot when the character is bogus. That's a very heavy-duty way of testing whether each character is a digit. I'm not convinced by the error recovery in the `catch` clause. Please delete this (before it's down-voted).