# How to convert from ASCII to INT

Tags: c++, char

I have a string "a" with numbers on it (e.g "I have 4 apples") and I'm trying to get the number "4" into an int variable without it giving me the ASCII code, in this case "52"(ASCII 4 is 52).

I have tried `int y = (int)a[8]` but it doesn't work.

Comment: try `atoi` https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/atoi/

Comment: Please describe the symptoms of "it doesn't work".

Comment: You want `y` to be equal to `4` or `52`?

Comment: @Yunnosch y still gets the ASCII value.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen 4

Comment: Another question like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/439573/how-to-convert-a-single-char-into-an-int

Comment: Thanks @Yksisarvinen! I'll check on it.

Comment: **You need first to specify** (on paper,  using [EBNF notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Backus%E2%80%93Naur_form)...) **the acceptable inputs**. In your case, is *"j'ai 4 pommes"* (the same phrase in French) an acceptable input? Once you can specify the valid input, you can start to write C++ code. You may want to read the [*Dragon book*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compilers:_Principles,_Techniques,_and_Tools)

Comment: You could also start a PhD in [Natural Language Processing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_language_processing). For that, find a good enough PhD advisor

Comment: Any kind of additional information (as requested in comments) is best [edit]ed into the question, instead of hidden down here in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

If the message is supposed to have the exact shape you gave as an example, then you can try the first part of the code below.

The `sscanf()` function analyses a string and can match literals as well as values you extract in variables.

**edit**
A more flexible version is provided too, in order to detect an integer anywhere in the string.
The idea is to extract the words one by one with `%s` and skip them thanks to the end position known with `%n`, until such a word is considered as an integer.

```
/**
  gcc -std=c99 -o prog_c prog_c.c \
      -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -Wconversion \
      -Wc++-compat -Wwrite-strings -Wold-style-definition -Wvla \
      -g -O0 -UNDEBUG -fsanitize=address,undefined
**/

#include <stdio.h>

int
main(void)
{
  // fixed shape for the message
  const char *msg="I have 4 apples";
  int number=-1;
  if(sscanf(msg, "I have %d apples", &number)==1)
  {
    printf("number=%d\n", number);
  }
  // more flexible version
  const char *msg2="Number 5 appears here";
  while(*msg2!='\0')
  {
    char word[20]="";
    int pos=-1;
    sscanf(msg2, "%s%n", word, &pos);
    int number=-1;
    if(sscanf(word, "%d", &number)==1)
    {
      printf("number=%d\n", number);
      break;
    }
    msg2+=pos; // skip this word
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yes, this code works for what I asked, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The way that I tend to do this is to subtract `'0'` from it.

e.g.

```cpp
char x = '8';
int y = x - '0';
```

A char is normally just an int and ASCII for digits is consecutive, so if you can get the offset from `'0'` to your digit, you get the value of the digit.